# Flutter_ffmpeg: HOW to merge/mix/overlay multiple stickers with video?

Tags: flutter, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg, mobile-ffmpeg

I try to mix multiple URL of sticker with video .

```
command= "-y -i ${video.path} -i ${sticker.url} -filter_complex \"[1:v]scale=100:100[ovrl];[0:v][ovrl]overlay=${sticker.offset!.dx}:${sticker.offset!.dy}\" -frames:v 900 -codec:a copy -codec:v libx264 -max_muxing_queue_size 2048 -preset ultrafast $outputFilePath",
```

Comment: you find answer?